# How do you use Control.Applicative to write cleaner Haskell?

Tags: haskell, coding-style

In a recent [answer to a style question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127190/good-haskell-coding-style-of-if-else-control-block/2096144#2096144), I wrote

```
main = untilM (isCorrect 42) (read `liftM` getLine)
```

and

```
isCorrect num guess =
  case compare num guess of
    EQ -> putStrLn "You Win!" >> return True
    ...
```

[Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17439/martijn) helpfully suggested alternatives:

```
main = untilM (isCorrect 42) (read <$> getLine)

EQ -> True <$ putStrLn "You Win!"
```

Which common patterns in Haskell code can be made clearer using abstractions from [Control.Applicative](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Control-Applicative.html)? What are helpful rules of thumb to keep in mind for using Control.Applicative effectively?

Answer (score 48):

There is a lot to say in answer to your question, however, since you asked, I will offer this "rule of thumb."

If you are using `do`-notation and your generated values[1] are not used in the expressions that you are sequencing[2], then that code can transform to an Applicative style. Similarly, if you use one or more of the generated values in an expression that is sequenced, then you must use `Monad` and `Applicative` is not strong enough to achieve the same code.

For example, let us look at the following code:

```
do a <- e1
   b <- e2
   c <- e3
   return (f a b c)
```

We see that in none of the expressions to the right of `<-` do any of the generated values (`a`, `b`, `c`) appear. Therefore, we can transform it to using Applicative code. Here is one possible transformation:

```
f <$> e1 <*> e2 <*> e3
```

and another:

```
liftA3 f e1 e2 e3
```

On the other hand, take this piece of code for example:

```
do a <- e1
   b <- e2 a
   c <- e3
   return (f b c)
```

This code cannot use `Applicative`[3] because the generated value `a` is used later in an expression in the comprehension. This must use `Monad` to get to its result -- attempt to factor it into `Applicative` to get a feel for why.

There are some further interesting and useful details on this subject, however, I just intended to give you this rule of thumb whereby you can skim over a `do`-comprehension and determine pretty quickly if it can be factored into `Applicative` style code.

[1] Those that appear to the left of `<-`.

[2] Expressions that appear to the right of `<-`.

[3] strictly speaking, parts of it could, by factoring out `e2 a`.

Comment: You can sometimes mix Monad and Applicative operators if you like the applicative style. Your second do block can be written `f <$> (e1 >>= e2) <*> e3`

Comment: +1 for concrete examples of when Applicative is sufficient, and when Monad is required.

Answer (score 45):

Basically, monads are also applicative functors [1]. So, whenever you find yourself using `liftM`, `liftM2`, etc., you could chain the computation together using `<*>`. In some sense, you can think of applicative functors as analogous to functions. A pure function `f` can be lifted by doing `f <$> x <*> y <*> z`.

Compared to monads, applicative functors cannot run its arguments selectively. The side effects of all the arguments will take place.

```
import Control.Applicative

ifte condition trueClause falseClause = do
  c <- condition
  if c then trueClause else falseClause

x = ifte (return True) (putStrLn "True") (putStrLn "False")

ifte' condition trueClause falseClause = 
  if condition then trueClause else falseClause

y = ifte' <$> (pure True) <*> (putStrLn "True") <*> (putStrLn "False")
```

`x` only outputs `True`, whereas `y` outputs `True` and `False` sequentially.

[1] [The Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia). Highly recommended.

[2] http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.html. Although this is an academic paper, it's not hard to follow.

[3] http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors. Explains the deal very well.

[4] http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html#id652399. Shows how the monadic `Parsec` library can also be used in an applicative way.

Comment: That's the only place I've seen where the difference between `Monad` and `Applicative` is explained (in terms of what you can express with each one). Great job!
Can we call `ifte` with the applicative functions: `z = ifte <$> ...` ?

Comment: `ifte` is already a monadic function, so there's not much point lifting it one more time.

Comment: You can write "ifte' <$> (pure True)" as "ifte' True"—"pure" is rarely necessary in combination with "<$>" and "<*>" (if at all).

Comment: y = ifte' True <*> putStrLn "True" <*> putStrLn "False"

Comment: It's `y = ifte' True <$> (putStrLn "True") <*> (putStrLn "False")` when you leave the `pure` away.

Answer (score 10):

See [The basics of applicative functors, put to practical work](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2008/02/06/the-basics-of-applicative-functors-put-to-practical-work/) by Bryan O'Sullivan.