# Haskell indentation style

Tags: haskell, coding-style, indentation

I find that I'm often inconsistent about how much I indent things, where I put in new lines, etc.. Are there official or widely followed guidelines for how one ought to layout whitespace in Haskell? Note that I'm not asking what's legal; I'm asking what's good practice, along the lines of [Good Haskell coding style of if/else control block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127190/good-haskell-coding-style-of-if-else-control-block) , but much more generally.  I'm particularly keen on knowing what people do with do-blocks, let-blocks, where-blocks and case statements, especially when such things are nested in each other or inside several function definitions.

Comment: [Indentation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) on Wikibooks should cover what you're looking for.

Comment: [Here's a good set of general Haskell style guidelines, including indentation](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md).

Comment: @David: that's about what's legal, not what's good practice.

Comment: I would have posted hammar’s comment as an answer if it were not already a comment. SE needs a „promote comment to answer vote“ button next to comments.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398996/good-haskell-source-to-read-and-learn-from) question might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

A small nitpick if I may.

I mostly like hammar's linked guideline. But, I really dislike this style:

```
send :: Socket
     -> ByteString
     -> IO Int
```

I much prefer

```
send ::
  Socket ->
  ByteString ->
  IO Int
```

In the latter style, the arguments and the result look different (the arguments have `->`s after them).

I like this better. People may disagree and it's mostly just matters of personal taste. Sadly afaik haddock seems to only support the former style :(

Comment: I also wonder if the 80 character per line rule is there in hindsight of people that need to punch their haskell source on cards?

Comment: @Ingo In my opinion, column limits use space better.  I typically put several columns of text side-by-side on screen.

Comment: @Heatsink very true. But why 80? Why not 72 or 96?

Comment: I dislike both styles equally, but I've yet to find a better option. When possible, I simply avoid type signatures too wide for one line.

Comment: Practical concerns on shared code make the first style preferable.  When reviewing signature changes in the second style, particularly changes that add new parameters to the end of a signature, more lines than necessary appear in the diff.  I prefer the first style and it is consistent with the preferred style for lists, data declarations, module exports, and several other Haskell constructs.  That said, I agree in part in that I also prefer not to wrap signatures at all (which throws away my whole merging argument) ;)